# how to pass same parameter for different values in API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I'm building an API to read data from stored procedure. I have to use same method to read different set of data by pass a different parameter in URL.

Below is how the paths look:

```
localhost:8080/api/PowerFeed/GetData/date/{date}/ClassID/{ClassID}
localhost:8080/api/PowerFeed/GetData/date/{date}/MainID/{MainID}
```

How do I use a single parameter to access different IDs in my method.

Method:

```
   public IHttpActionResult GetData(DateTime date, int ClassID)
    { 
     if(date == null)
     { 
         Logger.Debug(
         CommonConstants.Failed, 
         $"{nameof(PowerFeedController)}.nameof(GetData)}",
      CorrelationId);
      return BadRequest("Invalid request parameters. Cannot get data without
      date");
     }       
     var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
     IEnumerable<Power> records = null;
     if(ClassID >= 0)
     {     
       records = _dataAccessor.GetData(ApplicationName, date, ClassID);
       Logger.Debug(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(),
            $"{Operation.MeasureExecutionTimeInMilliseconds}-{nameof(PowerFeedDataAccessor)}.{nameof(_dataAccessor.GetData)}",
            CorrelationId)
     } 
     else
     {
       Logger.Debug(
       CommonConstants.Failed,
            $"{nameof(PowerFeedController)}.{nameof(GetData)}",
                CorrelationId);
       return BadRequest("Invalid request parameters. Cannot get data without ClassID");
     }
     return Ok(records); 
    }
```

In the above method, how would I pass MainID instead of ClassID, so that it can be called to get a different set of data?

Answer (score 1):

Is the shape of the data that's returned (the schema) the same in both instances? If so, something more like this would be preferred:

```
localhost:8080/api/PowerFeed/GetData/date/{date}&classID={ClassID}&mainID=MainID
```

and then in the controller:

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetData(DateTime date, int classID, int mainID)
 { 
   if(date == null)
     throw new NullReferenceException(); //etc
   if(classID == 0 && mainID == 0)
     throw new NullReferenceException(); //etc
   // do method for each case (ClassID or MainID) here
 }
```

If the shape / schema is different depending on the query, then you should have 2 separate controllers.

Comment: Yes the shape and schema are same. I will try this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can trya PUT request because then you can pass an entire object which could say just 'Id' and you could pass either values.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a PUT like below:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("startthread")]
public async Task<WebApiResponse> StartThread(StartThreadRequest request)
{
    // logic
    // return the response;
}
```